# Java Perform The Same Actions on Multiple Strings

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have several String variables that all need to be manipulated in the same way. (Lowercased, stripped of symbols and numbers, and repeated characters trimmed) Is there any way that I can change all these strings with a loop instead of having to list out all of them and perform the action to each one on a separate line?

```
obj1 = obj1.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "").[snip]
obj2 = obj2.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "").[snip]
obj3 = obj3.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "").[snip]
obj4 = obj4.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "").[snip]
```

...is what I have to do right now but I'd like to only have to write out the manipulation line once.

Comment: Put them in a list or array.

Comment: Are those "variables" instance fields or local variables?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Stream to get a List:

```
List<String> results = Stream.of(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4)
    .map(s -> s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "").[snip])
    .collect(toList());
```

Comment: That doesn't update obj1, obj2, obj3, and obj4 variables. Better answer would be to not have those variables in the first place, but use e.g. `String[4]` instead, so they can be updated in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Put all your objects into a list and then apply the logic to each one as follows:

```
myList.replaceAll(s -> s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "").[snip]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot optimize the updating of the objects due to the way Strings are implemented in Java.

You can, however extract the transformation into a method and invoke it on each variable, like (untested)

```
public String manipulate(String s) {
  return s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "").[snip];
}

....

obj1 = manipulate(obj1);
obj2 = manipulate(obj2);
obj3 = manipulate(obj3);
obj4 = manipulate(obj4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a array of string and than loop over that array, and perform the desired actions.

Example :

```
String arr[] = {"hello","hi","how"};
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  arr[i] = arr[i].toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8 lambda expression like the following:

```
String [] obj = {"a8848db", "AD87","AG88","Helo05484"};
Object [] arr =  Arrays.stream(obj).map( d -> d.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "")).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // Output [adb, ad, ag, helo]
```